# netbeans Command Line Argument using C:

Tags: c

Hi all on stackoverflow
I've changed from codeblocks to netbeans 12.6 writing a simple code:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int numberOfArguments = argc;
  char * Argument1 = argv[0];
  char * Argument2 = argv[1];

  printf("Number of arguments: %d\n", numberOfArguments);
  printf("Argument1 is the program name: %s\n", Argument1);
  printf("Argument2 is the command line argument: %s\n", Argument2);
  return 0;
}
```

I know to highlight project, click properties and goto run and open what do I do after that? Everthing I try nothing happens
Thank you in advanvce Frank

Comment: You have printed `argv[1]` without checking it is a valid pointer. When `argc` is `1`, then `argv[1]` will be a sentinel value `NULL` which you can't dereference. Note too that `argv[1]` isn't "the command line argument" but the *first* command line argument. Others will be in `argv[2]` etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, then read "[ask]" and [edit] your question. What is your question? -- If you don't know how to run a program in Netbeans with arguments, please see its documentation. This would be not a programming question, but a question how to use your IDE.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.